# ClamAV found infected files on Ubuntu server, what do I do now?

Tags: security, antivirus, clamav

I checked the Ubuntu server using the command `clamscan -r`. I don't know whether or not the files were cleaned or deleted. This is a screenshot of the results:

[image: virus found using clamav]

I'd like to know if these files still represent a menace to the server and if there's anything else I need to do.

I have also found that my server has been added to the [CBL email blacklist](http://cbl.abuseat.org/) and have since had problems with both incoming and outgoing email. Is this related and what can I do in this case?

Comment: As far as I know, the antivirus tools on linux are unable to "clean" files, only delete them. Those files look concerning, you will need to google search them to determine your next action. See https://www.virustotal.com/en/domain/sadmodem.com/information/ and similar

Comment: Are the files there? That should answer the deleted or not question. Just run `ls /var/www/clients/client1/web10/docente/archivos/Boss.pl`. If that shows you the file, you know it's not deleted.

Comment: I checked the files and they weren't deleted.

Comment: I deleted them manually, how can i run a complete scan and only log the infected files in scan_results.txt

Comment: According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV),ClamAV can only detect viruses and move any infected files into a quarantined folder; it cannot remove them from files. ClamAv detects viruses on all platforms, but it is primarily useful for Windows viruses and malware.

Comment: Am I the only one who does want to know the context of this and where the files came from? The path looks like a shared hosting model where users can upload files themselves. Well if the login wasn't secured and/or the password for the affected user was monkey or 123456, more than enough kiddies were happy to find that and place some bogus scripts there. If this assumption was more or less correct, then you don't have a virus, you have a **security breach**. Shut down the server and rethink your security model.

Answer (score 3):

Do these files represent a security problem? Yes.
Will deleting them fix the problem? No.

You've been hacked. Judging from the location of these files, somebody found an exploit in a web script you were running, and they've managed to download these applications. These have allowed them to go on and install more junk which is sending out spam. Hence the blacklisting.

There is no easy recovery from this. This install is compromised trash.

Rescue your data off it, and then work out *where* the breach was before you put it back online. **You cannot skip this** and that might involve hiring a professional to pick through your setup, but if you don't find the ingress point, and you just push the same websites back online, you're going to get hacked open again.

Comment: thanks, I discovered an unpatched XP machine on the network causing the problem, conficker was casuing our IP to enter into the Blacklist.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree, if these are simply in users inboxes it does not mean you've been hacked, it only meant someone sent them a virus, and since their computer (likely a Windows box) is now infected, IT is, through your server, sending out the infection to others, hence your machine being blocked.  But you should install clamav and wire it into your mail system to prevent further viruses from being sent to your clients and you should remove any infected mails from clients mailboxes which owing to lack of tools to repack an INBOX, is going to be a slow painstaking manual operation.